# Clock signal frequency

Tags: clock-speed

If the longest path that my digital signal must travel in a microprocessor is x cm. What would be the highest frequency of the clock signal for that chip?

Comment: Not enough information to give an answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on a false premise that distance somehow determines maximum frequency.

Answer (score 2):

That's unrelated:

There's no reason the left end of your IC needs to switch synchronously to the right end. Full stop – if you build an IC, that's inherently a distributed system, and skew is part of what you design for; if you need to combine two signals that travel a different distance, you compensate by adding a fractional delay to the "earlier" one, and add pipelining. That has no effect on clock rate; hence, no statement can be made about clock rate from travel distance.

Also:

Clock frequencies of digital logic ICs like CPUs are usually not limited by internal travel distances, but by the speed at which you can charge gate capacitances and at which transistors switch.

Answer (score 0):

This is called Signal Integrity.

To answer your question I should know:

1. The geometry and the layers stack-up of your printed circuit boards
2. The dielectric constant of the material of the PCB.
3. The termination resistance or the full termination network of the clock line.

Afterwards, I need to run a simulation at different frequencies.

Mentor Graphics Hyperlynx along with many other signal integrity simulators is able to solve your problem.

High speed PCB designers work 50% of their time in verifying signal integrity of high speed signals.